# Get calculated size of widget in GTK 4.0

Tags: gtk, gtk4

Is it possible to find out the calculated size of a widget, say, `GtkButton` and when the size changes under GTK 4.0? Ive tried a bunch of different things and none seem to work.

It looks like under GTK 3.0 it was possible to use a `size-allocate` signal, but that has been removed. I appreciate that this is very rarely needed, but surely there must be some way to know a) when the size has changed and b) what that new allocated size is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[size_allocate](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/vfunc.Widget.size_allocate.html) is a virtual method now. It is intended to be used only by the widget implementation itself, to assign sizes and locations to its children.

To get the size of a widget outside size_allocate, you can use [get_allocation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Widget.get_allocation.html).

If you're trying to keep another widget's size synced to the size of your button, you should use a [GtkSizeGroup](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.SizeGroup.html) instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Would i be right in assuming that `gtk_widget_get_allocated_width` is a shortcut for `gtk_widget_get_allocation` (ie, they should return the same results for width)? The problem that im finding is that `gtk_widget_get_allocated_width` returns decent results, but i dont know _when_ to call it to get the size when i update it. My use case is specific (and i think non-standard / rare), but in essence i have a button, when i click the button the label changes - id like to know the size of this button "at all times", including when it changes size. Any thoughts?

Comment: The best way to do that probably depends on why you need to know the size of the button. You might want to create a custom wrapper widget and implement its size_allocate method.

Comment: Thanks again James, i have played around with `g_main_context_iteration` and can get some "interesting" results, though i do feel at this point im misusing things. The custom wrapper is an interesting idea, i dont suppose you have any resources about how to go about that in C/C++ do you? Im also going to mark your answer as correct as i think for 99.9% of use cases it is correct - and for the other 0.1% case reevaluation is needed!